# Sphere rotation using theta and phi angles and/or visualisation of 3D kernel densities on sphere surface

Tags: r, data-visualization, rotation

I have data on sphere rotation described with cartesian coordinates and phi and teta angles.

I tried to represent a sphere with rgl.spheres() and make it rotate with rgl.viewpoint() in a loop but without success (only small variations). I would like to know if using this function is a good way to obtain a sphere rotation.

My second attempt was to plot 3d kernel density calculated with kde3d(x,y,z) of misc3d package on sphere surface with rgl.surface(), but I don't understand every argument of this function.

Could you give me a way to visualise this rotation in R ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you, but the example below shows how to rotate data coordinates in 3d space. You could use this in a loop to rotate your coordinates by a given series of degrees:

```
library(rgl)

###Data generation
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
mux <- 0
muy <- 0
muz <- 0
sdx <- 1
sdy <- 2
sdz <- 4
x <- rnorm(n, mux, sdx)
y <- rnorm(n, muy, sdy)
z <- rnorm(n, muz, sdz)

###Plot original coordinates
plot3d(x,y,z, t="s", col=8, size=3, aspect=c(1, dist(range(y))/dist(range(x)), dist(range(z))/dist(range(x))))

###rotate and tilt data
coord <- cbind(x,y,z)

theta <- 45
rotx <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,cos(theta),sin(theta),0,-sin(theta),cos(theta)), 3,3)
coord <- coord %*% rotx

theta <- 45
roty <- matrix(c(cos(theta),0,-sin(theta),0,1,0,sin(theta),0,cos(theta)), 3,3)
coord <- coord %*% roty

theta <- 30
rotz <- matrix(c(cos(theta),sin(theta),0,-sin(theta),cos(theta),0,0,0,1), 3,3)
coord <-  coord %*% rotz

###Plot rotated data
x <- coord[,1]; y <- coord[,2]; z <- coord[,3]
plot3d(x,y,z, t="s", col=8, size=1, aspect=c(1, dist(range(y))/dist(range(x)), dist(range(z))/dist(range(x))))
```

#### Original coordinates (largest spread on z-axis)

[image]

#### Rotated coordinates (largest spread is now tilted)

[image]